# how to plot LD between SNPs and CNVs

Tags: snp, heatmap, cnv, ld

I have a bunch of CNVs which I have estimated LD between each allele of CNV with all SNPs across the entire human genome. I used my R-script to do a pairwise LD analysis.

The following is the first few lines of my output for the first alternative allele of CNV and some SNPs on chromosome 2 (just as an example)

```
CNV_chrom  CNV_allele  SNP_chrom  SNP_position  R2
"1" "  CNV2"   "2"        " 1000"    "-0.0463767871013283" 
"1" "  CNV2"   "2"        " 1029"    "-0.201478578143067" 
"1" "  CNV2"   "2"        " 1044"    "-0.595441932439136"
"1" "  CNV2"   "2"        " 1045"    "-0.60363963711489"
"1" "  CNV2"   "2"        " 1130"    "0.377970958849221"
```

I want to plot the LD results (LD between each allele of CNV and all SNPs) ,is there any way that I could do it in R?

I have not done LD plotting before so just slightly confused.

I saw for instance [LDheatmap package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LDheatmap/index.html) in R, but do not know how can I summarize the results for thousands of SNPs. Thanks for any suggestion

---

Summary of LDHeatmap

> Produces a graphical display, as a heat map, of measures of pairwise
> linkage disequilibria between single nucleotide polymorphisms (SNPs).
> Users may optionally include the physical locations or genetic map
> distances of each SNP on the plot.

Citation

Shin, J.-H., Blay, S., McNeney, B., & Graham, J. (2006). LDheatmap: An R Function for Graphical Display of Pairwise Linkage Disequilibria Between Single Nucleotide Polymorphisms. Journal of Statistical Software, Code Snippets, 16(3), 1–9. https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v016.c03

Comment: There are a lot of ways to plot LD results.  Here are two links which might help.  http://csg.sph.umich.edu/abecasis/class/666.03.pdf  https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~mcclean/plsc731/Linkage%20Disequilibrium%20-%20Association%20Mapping%20in%20Plants-lecture-overheads.pdf They have a lot of different examples.